# Tabulator - Select dropdown list not clearing selected value

Tags: tabulator

I've run into an issue that is preventing me from clearing the option selected in the dropdown list. I'm using the field OEM in this example which is configured dropdown field (list editor). A dropdown menu opens up with all the values to select, along with the values I've added the clear option into editorParams which generate an x beside the option in the select which you can see in the gif I posted. However it is not allowing me to click it as the edit seems to be losing focus the moment I click that button and is no longer in an editable state.

Any suggestions on how to resolve it?

[Select Clear Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRzoS.gif)

Tabulator version: 5.2.7

Tabulator constructor:

```js
var quote_tracker = new Tabulator("#quote_tracker", {
    ajaxURL: "https://"+"<?php echo $host;?>/data/getQuotes.php", //ajax URL
    height: "82vh", 
    layout: "fitColumns", 
    //selectable: 1,
    pagination:true, 
    paginationButtonCount:3,
    paginationSize:2000, 
    paginationCounter:"rows",
    initialSort:[
        {column:"quote_id", dir:"desc"}
    ],
    columns: [ //Define Table Columns
        { title: "Quote #", field: "quote_id", sorter:"number",sorterParams:{alignEmptyValues:"bottom"}, hozAlign: "center", headerHozAlign: "center", tooltip: true, headerTooltip: true, editable:false, contextMenu:cellContextMenu},
        { title: "Sales Person", field: "sales_person" ,sorter:"string",sorterParams:{alignEmptyValues:"bottom"}, hozAlign: "center", headerHozAlign: "center", tooltip: true, headerTooltip: true, editable:false, contextMenu:cellContextMenu},
        { title: "Customer", field: "customer",sorter:"string",sorterParams:{alignEmptyValues:"bottom"}, hozAlign: "center", headerHozAlign: "center", tooltip: true, headerTooltip: true,widthGrow:2, editable:false, contextMenu:cellContextMenu},
        { title: "OEM", field: "oem", sorter:"string",sorterParams:{alignEmptyValues:"bottom"}, hozAlign: "center", headerHozAlign: "center", tooltip: true, headerTooltip: true, editable:false, contextMenu:cellContextMenu,editor:"list",
        editorParams:{values:oems,sort:"asc",clearable:true},
        cellDblClick:function(e, cell){
            cell.edit(editPerms);
        }},
        { title: "Program", field: "program",sorter:"string",sorterParams:{alignEmptyValues:"bottom"}, hozAlign: "center", headerHozAlign: "center", tooltip: true, headerTooltip: true, editable:false, contextMenu:cellContextMenu,editable:false,editor:"input",
        cellDblClick:function(e, cell){
            cell.edit(editPerms);
        }},
        { title: "Description", field: "description",sorter:"string",sorterParams:{alignEmptyValues:"bottom"}, hozAlign: "center", headerHozAlign: "center", tooltip: true, headerTooltip: true,widthGrow:2,editable:false,editor:"input", contextMenu:cellContextMenu,
        validator:function(cell,value){

            if(value.trim() == ""){
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        },
        cellDblClick:function(e, cell){
            cell.edit(editPerms);
        }},
        { title: "Contact", field: "contact",sorter:"string",sorterParams:{alignEmptyValues:"bottom"}, hozAlign: "center", headerHozAlign: "center", tooltip: true, headerTooltip: true,editable:false,editor:"input", contextMenu:cellContextMenu,
            cellDblClick:function(e, cell){
                cell.edit(editPerms);
        }},
        { title: "Location", field: "folder_location",sorter:"string",sorterParams:{alignEmptyValues:"bottom"}, hozAlign: "center", headerHozAlign: "center", tooltip: true, headerTooltip: true,widthGrow:2, editable:false,contextMenu:cellContextMenu},
        { title: "Comments", field: "comments", sorter:"string",sorterParams:{alignEmptyValues:"bottom"}, hozAlign: "center", headerHozAlign: "center", tooltip: true, headerTooltip: true ,widthGrow:2,editable:false,editor:"input",contextMenu:cellContextMenu,
            cellDblClick:function(e, cell){
            cell.edit(editPerms);
        }},
        { title: "Created Date", field: "create_date", sorter:"string",sorterParams:{alignEmptyValues:"bottom"}, hozAlign: "center", headerHozAlign: "center", tooltip: true, headerTooltip: true, editable:false, contextMenu:cellContextMenu, formatter:"datetime", formatterParams:{inputFormat:"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",outputFormat:"yyyy-MM-dd"}},
        //{ title: "Created By", field: "created_by", hozAlign: "center", headerHozAlign: "center", tooltip: true, headerTooltip: true },
    ],
    });
```

Comment: Checkout the 5.3 release in a weeks time, it contains some fixes to the list editor

Comment: @OliFolkerd Awesome work, seems to be working properly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to Tabulator Version 5.3 resolved this issue.